# Enabled / disabled repos in .repo file overwritten / superceded when new versions of software released?

Tags: mysql, yum

I'm working on installing MySQL from the yum repositories: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/

However our requirements are to run only MySQL 5.6, not the latest version 5.7.  So we don't want a 'yum update' to force an upgrade to a version higher than 5.6.

I've followed the steps here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html#yum-repo-select-series

to enable the subrepos for 5.6 and disable the ones for 5.7. I've installed and everything working fine so far.

I'm wondering what will happen when they release 5.8 though.  I assume an update will occur to the .repo file to add the 5.8 subrepo, and that it will be enabled by default.  It's my understanding that when subrepos for more than one version are enabled it will pick the more recent of the two.

So assuming my assumption above is right, at some point down the line I may run a yum update and have it automatically upgrade from 5.6 to 5.8.

What is the best solution to this issue?  I'd like to use the repos for ease of administration but need to run a version that is not the latest and do not want to find myself inadvertently upgrading to a newer version via yum update

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

On this page:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/updating-yum-repo.html

The explicitly state:

> By default, the MySQL Yum repository updates MySQL to the latest version in the release series you have chosen during installation (see Selecting a Release Series for details), which means, for example, a 5.6.x installation will NOT be updated to a 5.7.x release automatically.

So I guess this is a non-issue provided you've selected the Release Series you need at the outset as described here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html#yum-repo-select-series